# Access file upload field from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with accessing file upload field

```
//HTML
<input type='file' name='images' id="images" multiple>
//////////////////

    $('.bt-add-com').click(function(){
        var formdata = new FormData();
        var sessionID = 8;
        var theCom = $('.the-new-com');
        var theName = $('#name-com');
        var theMail = $('#mail-com');
        var theFile = formdata.append("images", sessionID);



        if( !theCom.val()){ 
            alert('You need to write a comment!'); 
        }else{ 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/add-comment.php",
                data: 'act=add-com&id_post='+<?php echo $id_post; ?>+'&name='+theName.val()+'&email='+theMail.val()+'&comment='+theCom.val()+'&file='+formdata.append("images[]", sessionID),
                success: function(html){
                    theCom.val('');
                    theMail.val('');
                    theName.val('');
                    $('.new-com-cnt').hide('fast', function(){
                        $('.new-com-bt').show('fast');
                        $('.new-com-bt').before(html);  
                    })
                }  
            });
        }
    });

    ////RESULT
    array (size=6)
    'file' => string 'undefined' (length=9)
```

problem is when i access file upload field using formdata as code below. it display value as undefined. can't get uploaded file details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're taking the form data object and appending it to a string. That won't work.

Don't try to build a string to pass to `data`, use the FormData API for *all* your fields, then pass the FormData object itself.

You also need to append the file data form the input instead of the number `8`.

```
formdata.append("images", sessionID);
formdata.append("images[]", sessionID)
```

Don't use `images` and `images[]`. If you're using PHP, then use just `images[]`

Don't use `sessionID`, use the file.

```
formdata.append("images[]", document.getElementById('images').files[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks bro.. it works after pass formdata object it self and adding this two lines 'contentType: false,
                processData: false,'